# Where to place rxvt extensions?

Tags: rxvt

I've trying to configure my rxvt-unicode so I need to know where to place extensions for it.
I've tried this folder: `~/.urxvt/ext/` and properly configured my `~/.Xdefaults` but no luck. Looks I should use some another folder but what the folder?

Comment: Do you want to use perl extensions for urxvt ? If so , you have to use the option "URxvt*perl-ext:" in the " ~/.Xresources" file. For more options , take a look at [here](https://www.askapache.com/linux/rxvt-xresources/)

Comment: @ParsaMousavi, that's right. But I need to download them from somewhere first? Or is it built-in in the rxvt?

Comment: There's another option named "URxvt*perl-lib:" . You can manually specify the directory where you've put the scripts.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I got it finally working!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add two options in your `~/.Xresources` :

```
URxvt*perl-lib: /your/perl/extensions/location
URxvt*perl-ext: # Comma-seperated list of extensions
```

You can find more options for customizing your terminal [here](https://www.askapache.com/linux/rxvt-xresources/).